# How to show custom route in Android.?

Tags: android, maps, routes, android-graphview

I am designing a route tracker app for Android. Now suppose I have this map.

[image]

Now the user can enter a source and a destination and my app will tell the route. Suppose the user has entered source and destination then my app should return the route as follows with first circle being source and other being destination..

[image]

What can I do to show only this much part of the image.? Is there any way I can draw a graph of my stops and then create a route using source and destination.? Any other way is also fine. Someone please help. Thanx in advance.